# QNAP Nas File Server outside LAN

Tags: port, file-sharing, webdav, file-server

I am trying to map my NAS as a network drive outside my LAN however I have very limited knowledge around this.

I have a QNap TS-212P which is configured to port forward so I can access it's GUI outside my LAN along with FTP.
I am now trying to configure WebDav via the Web Server. It is using port 8081 (https) and 80 (http). I have two user accounts which are both configured to access the Documents folder via WebDav.

When I try to map 192.168.0.4:8081 (inside LAN) or xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8081 (outside LAN) like so: \xx.xxx.xxx.xxx@SSL@8080\DavWWWRoot\Documents or \xx.xxx.xxx.xxx@80\DavWWWRoot\Documents I first get asked to log in, then get the error: "The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred: Mutual Authentication failed. The server's password is out of date at the domain controller."

I have tried to google the error, but haven't come across much relating to the Qnap NAS. Most people seem to have access straight away.
I have got Port 80 and 8081 port forward as well.

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong, or ways to set up a map to the drive outside the LAN a different way?

Cheers

Comment: `Mutual Authentication failed. The server's password is out of date at the domain controller` - Have you looked into that?

Comment: I have tried to google the error, but nothing seems to provide much information relating back to my QNAP device. Most resources I found related to a MS patch for the older versions of IIS.